# How to mutate filtered rows (using dplyr or if/else)

Tags: r, dplyr

Similar questions have been certainly asked but my one is much easier and unfortunately I really could not dissect the answer from them so here is my specific, probably simple case:

```
df <- data.frame("Sample" = 1:30,
                    "Individual" = c("a", "b", "c"),
                    "Repeat" = 1:3)
```

I would like to mutate the entry of Individual == "a" into "a_(number_of_repeat). But only for individual a, not for b or c.

I tried:

```
df[df$Individual == "a", ] <- 
df %>% filter(Individual == "a") %>%
df %>% mutate(Individual = paste0(Individual,"_",Repeat))
```

but no success. Maybe it could also be solved with a if/else or for argument?

```
df$Individual <- for (df$Individual == "a") {
df %>% mutate(Individual = paste0(Individual,"_",Repeat))
}
```

...also a fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this, with `mutate` and a classic `ifelse`:

```
  library(dplyr)
  df %>% mutate(Individual = ifelse(Individual=="a",
                                   paste0(Individual,'_',Repeat),
                                   Individual))
  Sample Individual Repeat
1       1        a_1      1
2       2          2      2
3       3          3      3
4       4        a_1      1
5       5          2      2
6       6          3      3
7       7        a_1      1
8       8          2      2
9       9          3      3
10     10        a_1      1
11     11          2      2
12     12          3      3
13     13        a_1      1
14     14          2      2
15     15          3      3
16     16        a_1      1
17     17          2      2
18     18          3      3
19     19        a_1      1
20     20          2      2
21     21          3      3
22     22        a_1      1
23     23          2      2
24     24          3      3
25     25        a_1      1
26     26          2      2
27     27          3      3
28     28        a_1      1
29     29          2      2
30     30          3      3
```

Or in a new column:

```
df %>% mutate(Individual_2 = ifelse(Individual=="a",
                                    paste0(Individual,'_',Repeat),
                                    Individual))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr::if_else`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(Individual = if_else(
        Individual == "a",
        sprintf("%s_%s", Individual, Repeat),
        Individual))
#   Sample Individual Repeat
#1       1        a_1      1
#2       2          b      2
#3       3          c      3
#4       4        a_1      1
#5       5          b      2
#6       6          c      3
#7       7        a_1      1
#8       8          b      2
#9       9          c      3
#10     10        a_1      1
#11     11          b      2
#12     12          c      3
#13     13        a_1      1
#14     14          b      2
#15     15          c      3
#16     16        a_1      1
#17     17          b      2
#18     18          c      3
#19     19        a_1      1
#20     20          b      2
#21     21          c      3
#22     22        a_1      1
#23     23          b      2
#24     24          c      3
#25     25        a_1      1
#26     26          b      2
#27     27          c      3
#28     28        a_1      1
#29     29          b      2
#30     30          c      3
```

Comment: s_t's code is a bit easier but thanks a lot for your quick reply!

Comment: @SebastianHesse no worries. I recommend using `if_else` instead of base R’s `ifelse` though. It’s typesafe and faster.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up some sytnax and therefore, your code fails.

First you `dplyr`-approach. Here you are close, but the additional df in the second row, messes up the pipeline.

```
df[df$Individual == "a", ] <- 
  df %>% filter(Individual == "a") %>%
  # don't pipe again df you already giving that as an input (just filtered)
  df %>% mutate(Individual = paste0(Individual,"_",Repeat))
```

The following makes it work:

Individual is stored as a factor, if you want to modify the column convert it to a character vector.

```
df$Individual <- as.character(df$Individual)
df[df$Individual == "a", ] <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(Individual == "a") %>%
  mutate(Individual = paste0(Individual,"_",Repeat))
```

There are other approaches as well:
E.g. in base R

```
df$Individual <- ifelse(df$Individual == "a", 
                        paste0(df$Individual, "_", df$Repeat), 
                        df$Individual)
```

Or in `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Individual = ifelse(Individual == "a", 
                             paste0(Individual, "_", Repeat), 
                             Individual))
```

You could also fix the for loop like below, but I really don't recommend that in this case as there are so nice vectorized options.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$Individual[i] == "a") {
    df$Individual[i] <- paste0(df$Individual[i], "_", df$Repeat[i])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of where my code was wrong!